# Which enzyme curdles milk in human infants?

Tags: enzymes, digestion, milk

Following, this question -

[Do humans produce rennin?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/65015/22601)
Rennin does not exist. 
And
[What inactivates pepsin in infants?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/what-inactivates-pepsin-in-infants)

Rennin exist.

**What do I know is-**

Rennin is found in calves and acts on milk to curdle it.

Pepsin acts as rennin at pH of 6-6.5 and curdles milk.

Humans have pepsin, in infants as well as adults. Pepsin can perform both functions in humans.

**So, in infants, is curdling of milk done by rennin or the rennin like activity of pepsin?**

Comment: @JM97 I read that answer before, but it says rennin exist in infants while in my question I am following a link which advocates, it does not. In, this post I wish to culminate both these, link together what really perform this function.

Comment: @David Please dont make this post duplicate to 2 posts that advocate 2 opposite things..

Comment: @Anubhav Please see the EDIT in another homo sapiens answer.

Comment: @AnubhavGoel — The two posts that between them certainly cover your question do not advocate anything. They ask questions. The answers may express different opinions or assumptions, but that is par for the course. It would perhaps be better if those two questions were merged to provide a more useful single resource, but that may be difficult to do now. You are asking for a clear cut answer when the answers to the other questions indicate there isn't one. I suggest you read them carefully and take from them what you can. Then it hardly matters which your post is classed as a duplicate of.